# Is there a way to re-install Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: gnome, 13.04, software-center

My Ubuntu Software Center keeps crashing and it won't open :(

This happened after I installed GNOME 3.10 and then I GNOME 3.10 but the issue keeps happening.

Is there a way to reinstall the USC?

Comment: Doing so is unlikely to fix the underlying problem...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Run the following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge software-center
sudo apt-get install software-center
```